# Ignore punctuation marks in taxonomy order by name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, order

Some of taxonomy terms names contains quotes, and this affects their order in list, if I use this query:

```
$term_args = array(
    'number' => $per_page,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'orderby' => 'name',
);
$terms = get_terms('my_taxonomy', $term_args);
```

Is there a way to ignore quotes (and maybe other punctuation marks) in terms order?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `'orderby'` parameter.

```
$term_args = array(
    'number' => $per_page,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
);
$terms = get_terms('my_taxonomy', $term_args);
```

WordPress slugs automatically remove punctuation and such so this is probably all you need to do in order to accomplish what you want.